# correct way of giving @media min-width or max-width

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to figure out if there should be an order (Increasing or decreasing) while giving @media in the css.

I am using some media with min-width, then if i write it in following order then what difference does it make with if i place it in increasing or decreasing order.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {

}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1365px) {

}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {

}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1150px) {

}
```

Comment: Start 'mobile' first my friend and add / overwrite styles as the viewport gets larger - you should have the largest query last.

Comment: Do it in descending way 1365 first ,then  1280

Comment: @gauravishere and Pratik Joshi -  maybe have a read up on this: http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?933 this device agnostic approach will save you lots of time and effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using min-width, then start with the minimum. because if browser gets two css condition suitable, it picks the later one. for example in following case-

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {

}
```

now if browser width is more than 1280, both condition are suitable for it. in this case it will pick second condition, i.e. (min-width: 900px). while it must choose (min-width: 1280px).

So always keep its order in mind.

Also same apply for the max-width condition. also give css condition with max-width in decreasing order. so you got the following -

`for min-width`

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {

}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1150px) {

}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {

}
```

`for max-width`

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px) {

}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1150px) {

}
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {

}
```